# VmWare and Powershell multi-valued attributes

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a question about multi-valued attributes and how to export them as csv.
While I know how to work with multi-valued attributes I've come to a dead end with this script that I am writing.
Here are the details:
I have to export a csv file that will contain VMName, HardDiskName, FileName etc.
At first I tried this approach (1):

```
$hdd = Get-HardDisk -VM "vmname" -DiskType RawPhysical| select Parent, Name
$props = @{'VMName' = $hdd.parent
'HDDName' = $hdd.name

}
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
#Write-Output $obj
$obj | Export-Csv vm.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I quickly realised that this approach won't work because I am dealing with multi-valued attributes and I won't be able to export them properly.
...than I tried this (approach 2)

```
$hdd = Get-HardDisk -VM "vmname" -DiskType RawPhysical| select @{Name='VmName';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.parent))}}, @{Name='HDDName';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.name))}}
$props = @{'VMName' = $hdd.parent
'HDDName' = $hdd.name
}

$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
#Write-Output $obj
$obj | Export-Csv vm.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Needles to say that this did not work either.

Some attributes are not multi-valued and I could get them with approach 1 but I cannot get the multi-valued attributes.

if I do this

```
$hdd = Get-HardDisk -VM svwdbn21 -DiskType RawPhysical| select @{Name='VmName';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.parent))}}, @{Name='HDDName';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.name))}},`
@{Name='FileName';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.filename))}}, @{Name='DeviceName';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.devicename))}},`
@{Name='CanonicalName';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.ScsiCanonicalName))}}| Export-csv test.csv
```

I can get almost all details I need except LUN info which I am getting it with the following piece of code:

```
$hdd = Get-HardDisk -VM "vmname" -DiskType RawPhysical| select parent, name, filename, devicename, ScsiCanonicalName
$Lun = Get-SCSILun $hdd.SCSICanonicalName -VMHost $vm.vmhost
$lunpaths=$lun|Get-ScsiLunPath
$luns = $lunpaths | select name, sanid, State, Preferred
$luns
```

... and here is where I got really stuck.
I need a way to combine in one csv file all the multi-valued atributes and LUN info which right now is stored in $luns.

after more research i come up with this:

```
$vm = Get-VM "vnname"| select name,VMHost
      $hdd = Get-HardDisk -VM "vmname" -DiskType RawPhysical| select Parent, Name, Filename, SCSICanonicalName, DeviceName
      $Lun = Get-SCSILun $hdd.SCSICanonicalName -VMHost $vm.vmhost
      $lunpaths=$lun|Get-ScsiLunPath
      $luns = $lunpaths | select name, sanid, State, Preferred
      $luns

      $props = @{'VMName' = $hdd.parent -join ';'
                'HDDName' = $hdd.name -join ';'
                'FileName' = $hdd.filename -join ';'
                'DeviceName' = $hdd.devicename -join ':'
                'CanonicalName' = $hdd.scsicanonicalname -join';'
                'LunName' = $luns.name -join ';'
                'SANId' = $luns.sanid -join ';'
                'State' = $luns.sate -join ';'
                'Preferred' = $luns.preferred -join';'

                }
      $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
      #Write-Output $obj
      $obj | Export-Csv vm.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

and while I get all the info that I need the csv file looks like this:

```
HardDisk LunName FileName

Hdd1;hdd2; lun1;lun2;lun3 filename1;filename2
```

but what I really want is this

```
HardDisk LunName FileName

Hdd1 lun1 filename1

hdd2 lun2 filename2

hdd3 lun3 filename3
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How do the LUNs map to the hard disks? Or do you just want running array entries? Your latest attempt is flattening the arrays into a single property but you want the opposite of that. You want to create an array of properties where each property is the combined elements from the other arrays.

Comment: Thank you Etan. I only need to get the array entries. 
Can you please show me how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you add example of an object returned by `Get-HardDisk` so we can try to mock your data? `Get-HardDisk | Export-Clixml` would be great.

Comment: Would it be possible to take this off-line for now until we sort this out and post the code after we are done.
I am afraid that this thread will get too long.